# Can a Raspberry Pi power 1 USB Asic Miner?

Tags: asic

Looking at other setups it seems everyone is running with multiple USB Asic Miners through powered USB Hubs. Can the Raspberry Pi power a single miner through USB? Even using a 2 amp power adapter?

Comment: Which ASIC USB miner? All of the bitcoin ASIC's on the market use USB.

Comment: Check this http://learn.adafruit.com/piminer-raspberry-pi-bitcoin-miner

Comment: I probably wouldnt recommend this, only because an ASIC usb miner takes about 2.5W alone, just to power. So be sure to use a usb hub with its own power source. Haha. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/340/how-much-power-can-be-provided-through-usb) it seems that the USB ports on the RPi cannot exceed 100mA so it probably wouldn't be a good idea to use a Block Erupter directly on the RPi

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

I have been running my Pi (B, 512mb) with a 1.5 amp power supply with 1 usb erupter (Sapphire) for over a week with no problems. Directly connected to the Raspberry, no hub.

Answer (score 1):

Put it into a powered USB hub, then connect the hub to the PI.

Answer (score 0):

This answer depends on the board revision of the Raspberry 
for older boards you have a 100mA limit

this limit is no longer valid for Raspberry Model B Revision 2.0 but better use a powered USB HUB without on/off button

> `Rev 1.0 = MAX 1A`
>
> `Rev 2.0 = MAX 2.5A`

[Raspberry Official Source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/upcoming-board-revision/)